# Size of metricbeat metricsets/fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, metricbeat

I've been tasked with reducing the footprint on disk of our Metricbeats. We have a number of modules active, each with a set of metricsets, which each in turn have all the defaults uploading.

We're using an enormous amount of storage. I would like to write up what fields we can get away with dropping entirely, and also include an estimate for what % this will reduce our storage usage.

Is there anywhere where storage requirements/ranges are given for metricbeat metricsets, or even whole modules? Maybe on a per-document basis? I'm hoping there's some approximations available, but I've come up empty handed so far.

Comment: what's "an enormous amount of storage"?

Comment: An amount that would materially reduce spend if I could reduce each document by a KB or two.